# Python requests throwing "certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate" error

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

When trying to call an API using python Requests I'm getting `certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate` error.

I have added the SSL certificate in **cacert.pem** of certifi. This did not fix the problem.

```
data = {'foo':'bar'}
url = 'hostname'
r = requests.post(url, data=data)

print(r)
```

The above code only works when I put **verify=False** in the above code.

I have also extracted SSL certificate of API using the below code and added it to certifi **cacert.pem** but that too did not work.

```
import ssl, socket
myhostname = 'hostname'
myctx = ssl.create_default_context()
myctx.check_hostname = False
myctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
s = myctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=myhostname)
s.connect((myhostname, 443))

bcert = s.getpeercert(binary_form=True)
cert = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(bcert)
```

Below is the error that is getting thrown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 976, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 361, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 377, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` to point to your certs?  I’ve had issues before where I’ve had to explicitly set that value and that fixed cert issues (the default certs with python did not work with the self-signed certificates on the sites I needed to hit).

Comment: Yes, I have set REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE to my cert. This did not solve the issue.

Comment: It does not help to add a normal leaf certificate to cacert.pem since it is not a CA cert. It is unclear if this is the case here or not since nothing is known about the target and its certificate and what initially caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I have also extracted SSL certificate of API

My guess is that you used leaf server certificate as CA, and that's not how cert validation works. The SSL library on your side is trying to build a trust chain. Typical server certificate chain looks like this:

(CA ->) Intermediate CA -> server certificate

The CA cert is not sent in the TLS handshake with the server. It's your ssl client's job to find a matching trusted CA for the chain.

You have to add CA to CA_BUNDLE not leaf server cert.

How to get the CA cert? Try in your browser and click on the lock, the CA cert will be upmost in the chain if it's found.

You can also inspect the cert and find out who signed it (issuer attribute). Maybe you'll be able to find that issuer's cert in some public CA database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.As suggested by you, I have already added CA, Intermediate and Leaf server certificate to cacert.pem of certifi. But I.m still getting the same error.

Comment: How did you obtain the certs? How did you verify that CA is actually the CA?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program code below:

```py
# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )


def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi

    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b:\d\my\py\wget.py", line 55, in <module>
    update_cert_store()
  File "b:\d\my\py\wget.py", line 26, in update_cert_store
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\SSL'

Comment: Try `pip install certifi`

Comment: Already had done that.

Comment: Then open a new question with a detailed step-by-step explanation of what you want to get and where your problem is, there you will describe the mistakes you have so it will be easier to help you.